# Mail not going from SMTP

Tags: 6, emails

I have configured the smtp for drupal , as said in this link [`https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp`](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) and my smtp module folder lies in **`/sites/all/modules/smtp`** and phpmailer library lies in **`/sites/all/libraries/phpmailer`** .
But am getting the following error on sending the test mail from the drupal admin `SMTP authentication support` .

**2015-07-09 14:37:30 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-07-09 14:41:45 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 2015-07-09 14:41:45 Connection: opening to ssl://:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-07-09 14:41:45 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) 2015-07-09 14:41:45 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

And these are my smtp parameters ,
[image]

Any help is appreciated . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Your host cannot reach *smtp.gmail.com* on port *465*. It sounds like a network connectivity problem, not a Drupal problem. Run the command `nc -zv smtp.gmail.com 465` to confirm.

You may need to talk your hosting provider if they have restrictions in place. My guess, if they are blocking it, is they are blocking SMTP access to GMail to prevent spam.